# compile opencv on macos error - error in libavformat

Tags: ffmpeg, opencsv

I've tried compiling OpenCSV in two macs and in both I have errors. The errors follow:

```
Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
use of undeclared identifier 'avformat_find_stream_info'; 
did you mean 'av_find_stream_info'?
/usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1168:5: note: 'av_find_stream_info' declared here int av_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext *ic);
```

The libavformat in /usr/local/include was installed with ffmpeg. Ffmpeg is the 0.8.5 version

Anyone has this same issue?

Comment: opencsv is a Java library for parsing files with comma separated values.  Did you mean OpenCV, the computer vision library?

Answer (score 2):

I basically edited the code in modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp from

```
#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(53, 3, 0)
    avformat_find_stream_info(ic, NULL);
#else
    av_find_stream_info(ic);
#endif
```

to

```
#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(53, 3, 0)
    av_find_stream_info(ic);
    //avformat_find_stream_info(ic, NULL);
#else
    av_find_stream_info(ic);
#endif
```

and that solved it. No problems so far.

Comment: Thank you. Same problem, same version of ffmpeg, same solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable ffmpeg by adding the following arguments to the `cmake` command (see for example [this manual](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/)):

```
-DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF
```

Assuming you don't actually need ffmpeg in your build, this will get rid of the error.